# Automapper Create.Map() leads to NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, automapper

I have no idea but I followed some steps on how to do automapper. [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions)

Here is my scenario:

My main class:

```
public class Customer
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string Company { get; set; }

  public string GetFullName()
  {
    return string.Format("{0}, {1}", this.LastName, this.FirstName);
  }
}
```

my ViewModel:

```
public class CustomerVM
{
  public string FullName { get; set; }
  public string Company { get; set; }
}
```

then do the mapping:

```
Mapper.Create<Customer, CustomerVM>()
      .ForMember(dto => dto.Company, opt => opt.NullSubstitute("No Company"));
```

then storing it:

```
var customers = _customerSerivce.All.Project().To<CustomerVM>().toList():
```

Now my question is, I don't understand why it gave me and `NRE` error. Also, some issues regarding the `flattening`. It also gives me `NRE` error. I sure do have some `null` records. I am using `Entity Framework`

What did I missed? Any thought? Thanks

Comment: How are you mapping `FullName`? Shouldn't `class Customer` have a property `public string FullName { get { return ...`

Comment: It says in the documentation. That `flattening` of property works automatically that include `Get` functions

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `NullSubstitute` (along with many other methods) can't work with LinQ-generated queries. In the case, the following code must produce no errors:

```
Mapper.Create<Customer, CustomerVM>()
    .ForMember(dto => dto.Company,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(T => T.Company ?? "No Company"));
```

Comment: Thanks mate. But still, didn't worked. I don't know what's wrong.